# configure a range of cells in spreadsheet to auto link to an email or to a website

Tags: excel, ms-office

I just hope anyone can help me on how to configure a range of cells in spreadsheet to auto link to an email or to a website so that when you click an email in a cell, a new window or outlook will open to send an email.

I am not sure if there's a way to do this automatically that as you type in or paste the email, it will be clickable and will be able to send an email using outlook.

I've done some research and watched some YouTube tutorials but I haven't found the answer yet.

Thanks in advance for those who can give me some feedback

Comment: tried [ r-click > hyperlink ] ?

Comment: Can you please clear it how you explained I cannot understand it sorry and thank you

Comment: Do it on the "range of cells in spreadsheet" that you want to "auto link". and explore the options and help.. share us the steps where you tried and stuck at so others can help. | Btw, any sample data / link / email / excel file you can share as a demo ?